# iTextSharp: Trying to make TextField transparent: PdfContentByte is nothing

Tags: itext

I want to add textfields to my PDF.
These textfields' backgrounds should be transparent.

I have found an example on the web that showed how to do this the following way:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("TransparencyPDF.pdf"));
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        
PdfGState gs1 = new PdfGState();
gs1.setFillOpacity(0.5f);
        
cb.setGState(gs1);
```

However, in my code, I don't have a PDFWriter. I have a PDFStamper.
But its properties look perfectly the same, so I adopt it like this:

```
Dim cb As PdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(0)
Dim gs As New PdfGState
gs.FillOpacity = 0.5
cb.SetGState(gs)
```

The last line throws the error "System.NullReferenceException: cb is nothing."

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

This is my entire code:

```
Dim stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(New PdfReader(sInputFile), File.Create(sOutputFile))

Dim iPageNumer As Integer = 1

Dim tf As TextField
tf = New TextField(stamper.Writer, New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(iLowerLeftX, iLowerLeftY, iUpperRightX, iUpperRightY), n.Name)
Dim bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, False)
With tf
    .Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT And Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE '  Element.ALIGN_CENTER And Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE
    .BackgroundColor = GrayColor.WHITE
    .BorderColor = Color.RED
    .BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_SOLID
    .DefaultText = "This is a new text field."
    .Font = bf
    .FontSize = 7
    .MaxCharacterLength = 25
    .Options = TextField.BORDER_WIDTH_MEDIUM ' TextField.REQUIRED Or TextField.MULTILINE
    .Rotation = 0 '90
    .Text = "" 'This is the assigned value."
End With

stamper.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField(), iPageNumer)

Dim cb As PdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(0)
Dim gs As New PdfGState
gs.FillOpacity = 0.5
cb.SetGState(gs) 'This line throws the error. cb is nothing. Why?

stamper.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with

```
Dim cb As PdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(0)
```

is that it requests the `OverContent` of page `0` while page numbering in iText starts at `1`. Thus, use

```
Dim cb As PdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1)
```

instead.